# JavaScript optimization: Caching math functions globally

Tags: javascript, optimization

I'm currently doing some "extreme" optimization on a JavaScript game engine I'm writing. And I have noticed I use math functions a lot! And I'm currently only caching them locally per function I use them in. So I was going to cache them at the global level in the window object using the below code.

```
var aMathFunctions = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Math);

for (var i in aMathFunctions)
{
    window[aMathFunctions[i]] = Math[aMathFunctions[i]];
}
```

Are there any major problems or side effects with this? Will I be overwriting existing functions in window, and will I be increasing my memory footprint dramatically? Or what else may go wrong?

EDIT: Below is an excerpt on reading I have done about JavaScript optimization that has lead me to try this.

> Property Depth
>
> Nesting objects in order to use dot notation is a great way to
>   namespace and organize your code. Unforutnately, when it comes to
>   performance, this can be a bit of a problem. Every time a value is
>   accessed in this sort of scenario, the interpreter has to traverse the
>   objects you've nested in order to get to that value. The deeper the
>   value, the more traversal, the longer the wait. So even though
>   namespacing is a great organizational tool, keeping things as shallow
>   as possible is your best bet at faster performance. The latest
>   incarnation of the YUI Library evolved to eliminate a whole layer of
>   nesting from its namespacing. So for example, YAHOO.util.Anim is now
>   Y.Anim.

Reference: http://www.phpied.com/extreme-javascript-optimization/

Comment: I'd be amazed if that speeded up your game.  Have you measured the performance difference?

Comment: Why do you do this in the first place?

Comment: So the only difference will be e.g. `floor` instead of `Math.floor`? I'm not sure at all whether that makes any difference in performance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit:** Should not matter anymore in Chrome due to [this revision](https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/detail?r=10640); perhaps caching is now even faster.

---

Don't do it, it's much slower when using global functions.

http://jsperf.com/math-vs-global

On Chrome:

```
sqrt(2);      - 12,453,198  ops/second
Math.sqrt(2); - 542,475,219 ops/second
```

As for memory usage, globalizing it wouldn't be bad at all on the other hand. You just create another reference; the function itself will not be copied.

Comment: So would i also avoid caching with a function as well? Eg use Math.sqrt instead of var sqrt = Math.sqrt;

Comment: A rather amazing difference in speed there!

Comment: I just ran the supplied test in your answer in Firefox 5 (the browser im using for development) and it was faster to cache the math functions. Now I'm a bit stuck on whether to do it or not

Comment: @Tristan: Interesting, but I would not mind about it. The difference on Chrome is much more, so you can choose between 'really fast on Chrome and a little drawback on Firefox' or 'a little faster on Firefox and much slower on Chrome'.

Comment: Yep ran it with 5.0.1 and much faster. @Tristan if you really need to optimize it, you can do different versions for different browsers. :D

Comment: Yeah I guess different version is possible, though quite painful, eventual I plan on embedding the code in a Qt application even though I will have a web version as well so I may just stick to what works best with V8

Answer (score 3):

I am actually amazed it is faster for me on Mac OS X and Firefox 5 talking 5-8 ms difference in 50000 iterations.

```
console.time("a");
for (var i=0;i<50000;i++) {
    var x = Math.floor(12.56789);
}
console.timeEnd("a");

var floor = Math.floor;

console.time("b");
for (var i=0;i<50000;i++) {
    var y = floor(12.56789);
}
console.timeEnd("b");
```

I see only one real bonus if it will reduce the footprint of the code. I have not tested any other browsers so it may be a boost in one and slower in others.

Would it cause any problems? I don't see why it would unless you have things in global scope with those names. :)

Comment: I do have to say that on Chrome it's always about 10ms slower.

Comment: Webkit looks like it optimizes differently. What a surprise lol ;)

Comment: It would be nice lowering the footprint of the code but not at the expense of performance and i'm still a little unsure as to any side effect there may be adding all those functions to global, though I honestly can't think of any

Comment: @Tristan: If you simply want a lower footprint, you might be interested in http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home. It shortens your code without making it do something different.